# Add infobox to polygon drawn using drawing manager in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infobox

I have setup the Drawing Manager, and I can easily draw polygon using it. Now I want to add a Info-box on this drawn polygon. I used the below code, but it seems it's not working as no Info-box results.

```
    drawingManager.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
        if (event.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
            var reason = prompt("Please Mention the reason for this obstuction");
            var authority = prompt("Please Mention the authority involved");

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: reason + ", Raised by " + authority,
                width: "50px"
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay,'mouseover',function(){
                infowindow.open(map,event.overlay);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay,'mouseout',function(){
                infowindow.close(map,event.overlay);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why dont you add your handlers to the overlay object in the manager, when you create it?  Seems like the overlay needs to know mouse over, and mouse leave to show it's information.

Comment: because, I wanted to perform my action when drawing of overlay is completed. i.e., i wan to add an info-box when drawing of polygon using drawing manager is completed,therefore adding event listener for showing infobox on mouse over

Comment: when you create the polygon and pass in your options, it's actually available to the map at that time.  No need to wait for another event.

Comment: why is this tagged [google-maps-api-2](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-2/info)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you are asking for Polygon. You do not have to use overlay object. You can directly use Polygon object to draw shapes as well as listen the polygon complete option.

Following is the demo which will enable you to draw polygon shape and will produce a infoWindow at the middle of the polygon shape which you have drawn.

Working [Demo](http://jsbin.com/niwonatu/1/edit).